# AttributeError: 'TraitCompound' object has no attribute 'clone'

Tags: python, enthought

Let's say I want to create, using the Traits package, a "bases" attribute that can be  a 'none' string or a dictionary with keys which are ‘hrf’ or ‘fourier’ or ‘fourier_han’ or ‘gamma’ or ‘fir’ and with values which are a dictionary with keys which are ‘derivs’ or ‘length' or ‘order’ and with values which are a list or a float). Ex:

bases == 'none'
or
bases == {'hrf': {'derivs': [0, 0]}}
or
bases == {'fourier': {'length': 1.4, 'order': 3}}

if I define a 'none' string or a dictionary with keys which are ‘hrf’ or ‘fourier’ or ‘fourier_han’ or ‘gamma’ or ‘fir’ and with values which are a dictionary with keys which are ‘derivs’ or ‘length' or ‘order’ and with values which are a list) it's working fine:

```
>>> import traits.api as traits
>>> class Foo(traits.HasTraits):
...  bases = traits.Either(traits.Dict(traits.Enum("hrf","fourier","fourier_han","gamma","fir"),traits.Dict(traits.Enum("derivs","length","order"), traits.List)),'none',default={"hrf":{"derivs":[0,0]}})
... 
>>> foo=Foo()
>>> foo.bases
{'hrf': {'derivs': [0, 0]}}
```

But this is not exactly what I want. If now I try to give the possibility to use list or float in the inside dictionary, it's not working:

```
 >>> import traits.api as traits
 >>> class Foo(traits.HasTraits):
...  bases = traits.Either(traits.Dict(traits.Enum("hrf","fourier","fourier_han","gamma","fir"),traits.Dict(traits.Enum("derivs","length","order"), traits.Either(traits.List, traits.Float))),'none',default={"hrf":{"derivs":[0,0]}})
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in Foo
  File "/home/econdami/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traits/trait_types.py", line 2804, in __init__
    handler = handler.clone()
AttributeError: 'TraitCompound' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

why ?

Comment: Please could you open an issue on the bug tracker?

Comment: (I removed the "traits" tag, because it's referring to a different usage/meaning of "traits".)

Comment: I've opened a ticket on the [enthought/traits github](https://github.com/enthought/traits/issues/1092). Is that what you're proposing? thanks for the tag remove.

Comment: Thank you very much! And yes, that's what I meant. This looks like a possible bug to me. (I'm the current maintainer of the Traits library, but only during work hours.)

Comment: Thank you very much and sure this can be wait the work hours !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the first time I've interact with the team that develops the Traits project.

[As always, they very quickly managed to solve the problem and gave a very detailed answer on it.](https://github.com/enthought/traits/issues/1092#issuecomment-631371794)

In a nutshell, as early as Traits 6.1, on the one hand, prefer:

```
traits.Union(traits.Float, traits.List)
```

to

```
traits.Either(traits.Float, traits.List)
```

On the other hand, pay attention to the `default_value` argument for Union() (`default` for Either()). It would be better to initialise it by other means.